# How can I organize subarrays in numerical order from within a larger array?

Tags: javascript

Question 1: Clean the room function: given an input of [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20], 
make a function that organizes these into individual array that is ordered. For example 
Answer(ArrayFromAbove) should return: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,
[20,20], 391, 392,591]. 
Bonus: Make it so it organizes strings differently from number types.  i.e. [1, "2", "3", 2] 
should return [[1,2], ["2", "3"]]

[1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20]

I'm not sure how to change a number in the original array into a subarray that can be added to.

```
const cleanRoom = array => {
    let newArray = [];
    array.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    array.forEach(item => {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(newArray[i] === item || newArray[i[i]] === item) {
                newArray[i] = newArray[[i]];
                newArray[[i]].push(item);
            } else {
                newArray.push(item);    
            }
            }

    })
    return newArray
}
```

cleanRoom([1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20])

What I've tried here just gives me a type error but I was hoping it would return: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591].

Comment: `newArray[[i]]`: An array is not an index.

Comment: Hint: (1) sort; (2) find runs, and turn them to lists, even of length 1; (3) turn runs of length 1 to scalars.

Comment: So, what is the groping on? Any items that have the same value? But if you have different *types*, the grouping should be on the type instead of the value? How should the sorting be done in that latter case, then - do you sort numerically, even if values might not convert to numbers? Do you sort lexicographically? What do you sort on - first value, last value, something else?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like one should sort tuples of `(x, tyepof x)` form to get what the problem description suggests. This works: `array.map(x => [x, typeof x]).sort().map(x => x[0])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first count up occurrences by `reduce`ing into an object indexed by number, whose values are the number of times that number has occurred so far. Then map those object's entries to a new array. If the count is 1, return a single number, otherwise, return an array with that many numbers:

```js
const cleanRoom = array => {
  const countObj = array.reduce((a, num) => {
    a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(countObj)
    .map(([num, count]) =>
      count === 1 ? Number(num) : new Array(count).fill(Number(num))
    );
};

console.log(cleanRoom([1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]));
```

Comment: This converts the type from numeric to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that sorts the array as well

```js
const cleanRoom = array =>
    Object
        .entries(array.reduce((a, e) => (a[e] = (a[e] || 0) + 1) && a, {}))
        .map(([key, count]) => [Number(key), count])
        .sort(([k1, o1], [k2, o2]) => k1 > k2)
        .map(([key, count]) => count == 1
            ? key
            : Array(count).fill(key)
        );

console.log(cleanRoom([1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might work:

```
let array = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20]
array.sort((b, c) => b - c);
grouped = array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
    if (v === a[i - 1]) {
        r[r.length - 1].push(v);
    } else {
        r.push(v === a[i + 1] ? [v] : v);
    }
    return r;
}, []);
console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, "2", "3", 2]
var number = [];
var char = [];
var org = arr.forEach(v => (typeof v === "number") ? number.push(v) : char.push(v));
org = [].concat([number], [char])
console.log(org);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.